# .NET Core Conditional publishing depending on Published Target Runtime

Tags: c#, .net-core, csproj

Is there a way to check what the published target runtime is? There are different sets of deploy files that I want to copy to the publish directory depending on whether the target runtime is Linux or Windows. What would be the macro/property for checking the published runtime? I'm attempting to do something like the below:

```
<Target Name="CopyFiles" AfterTargets="Publish" Condition="$(TargetRuntime) == Linux-64">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(PublishDir)" Condition="!Exists('$(PublishDir)Deploy')" />
    <Copy SourceFiles ="$(SolutionDir)*" DestinationFolder ="$(PublishDir)Deploy" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are likely looking for `$(RuntimeIdentifier)` - e.g.:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(RuntimeIdentifier)' == 'linux-x64'">
  <Content Update="foo.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

(Assuming it is a content item, could be `None` as well depending on the project type)

Comment: You just saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone knows why a Condition based on `RuntimeIdentifier` is not honored when using Publish from within Visual Studio? It seems to always be windows, and messing up the build that's published.